# Time series forecasting using ARIMA model

Tags: python, pandas, forecasting

Is there a way to predict future values of a column based on its values on a monthly basis till date? How do we get the values for the next say 6 months?

Answer (score 0):

> **statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA**
>
> *class statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA(endog, order, exog=None, dates=None, freq=None, missing='none')*
>
> Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average ARIMA(p,d,q) Model

You need more than pandas. I will introduce [statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) library for statistics. (Especially ARIMA, please check one of these [examples](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/index.html).) statsmodels works well with pandas.

You should use `.predict()` method of it for prediction.